# Trying to delete string characters

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to delete characters in a string by replacing them with empty quotes. It's giving me the following error message:

```
incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to
      'char' from 'char [1]' [-Wint-conversion]
        source[i] = "";
                  ^ ~~
```

I'm getting the same error when I replace the empty string with a character and I thought this was the procedure for replacing array elements, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int removeString(char source[], int startIndex, int numberRemove) {
    int i;
    for (i = startIndex; i < startIndex + numberRemove; i++) {
        printf ("%c", source[i]);
        source[i] = "";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(source); i++) {
        printf("%c\n", source[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main (void) {
    char text[] = { 'T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'o', 'n', 'g', ' ', 's', 'o', 'n' };

    removeString(text, 4, 6);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign "" to a char! "" is a char * (It's better to say an ASCII0 string).

I think you want insert a 0 code in the string! This is not a good choice because 0 indicates the end of an ASCII0 string.

You may substitute the char with a space:

```
source[i] = ' ';
```

But I think it's not what you want!

To take off the char from the string you have to move all chars after the char you want remove on the char to be deleted.  ;)

If you want that an ASCII0 string is printed and managed as a void string
just put a 0 in the first byte!!!

```
source[0]=0;
```

or

```
*source=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
memset(source, 0, strlen(source));
```

This will set the entire string length to null terminate char. What you are doing above:

```
source[i] = "";
```

is an error for several reasons:

1. When you set a char in C, you use single quotations: ''
2. empty and null terminate char are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Basically I'm looping over the string and printing out the chars if they are within the specified value range.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int removeString(char source[], int startIndex, int numberRemove) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(source); i++) {
        if (i < startIndex || i >= startIndex + numberRemove) {
            printf("%c", source[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main (void) {
    char text[] = { 'T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'o', 'n', 'g', ' ', 's', 'o', 'n', '\0' };

    removeString(text, 4, 6);

    return 0;
}
```